# All native cordova plugins stopped working on Ionic3

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

The app uses some standard ionic/native plugins including callNumber, SMS, Facebook, SocialSharing, Clipboard and at some point I realised that all of them stopped working when running on the xCode simulator or an actual iOS device (haven't yet built it for android). They were working flawlessly before...

I understand that it'll not be easy to figure out the cause with no code but just looking for hunches or methods to follow in the debugging since I'm new to debugging ionic apps' native functionality.

Comment: Try this: `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json platforms plugins` then run `npm install` followed by `ionic cordova platform add ios`. If it still does not work try reinstalling node and npm.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

It seems your environment is having a serious issue. So I would like to suggest an alternative here.That is, You can use [**Ionic package service**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/package/).

> Ionic Pro’s Package feature makes it easy to build native app binaries
>   for iOS and Android in the cloud. Perfect for automating binary builds
>   and for developers using Windows that want to build iOS apps.

**Old Answer:**

You can try this:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
```

After that:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: Thanks @sampath, how are you thinking this is going to help?

Comment: It'll add the Cordova plugins correctly if something went wrong with your current platform setup.

Comment: I tried that and when I re-add ios I get that ios is not detected and when I follow its suggestion to add it I go through the same thing on repeat:

Running command - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.
> cordova platform save
✔ Running command - done!
> ionic cordova resources ios --force
✔ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!

? Platform ios not detected. Would you like to install it? Yes
> cordova platform add ios --save
✖ Running command - failed!

Comment: It seems you have an issue on your environment.Maybe restart your MAC will be helped.

Comment: Just rebooted: same results!

Comment: Please see the **Update** above.